# Best way to keep pagination after editing a record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm very new to Laravel and I'm trying to make a crud application with a view for each db table that has a list with edit buttons on each record.
So far I have the paginated list which is working good and an edit view that is working as well.
The problem I'm facing is that whatever page I'm in I can click the edit button and edit the record successfully, but when I save the record I always go back to page 1.
I don't know and I'd like to know which is the correct (best) way to achive this.
Should I use session? Or maybe append the page parameter to the edit form action? Or else?

EDIT:
this is what edit method returns:

```
return redirect('/lyrics')->with('success', 'Lyric updated!');
```

Thank you for any help that points me in the right direction.

Comment: The two approaches you've mentioned (session, or GET parameters) are what came to my mind when reading your question. I feel that using the session would be the cleaner solution, and could also seemlessly benefit you in other tasks. E.g. deletion.

Comment: It would be nice to know the reason of the downvote so I can learn to improve my next questions

Comment: show what you return in update method

Comment: @RubenDanielyan thanks for your comment: I've edited the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the page parameter to the edit page and then after the user update the record, you can redirect to the page you were in.

Something like this:

In the link where you call the edit page:

```html
<a href="{{ route('someroutename')}}&page={{ app('request')->input('page') }}">Edit</a>
```

In your edit form:

```html
<form>
  ... fields
  <input type="hidden" name='page' value={{ app('request')->input('page') }}
</form>
```

Then in your update method at the controller

```php
public function update($request)
{
    // update
    return redirect('homepage', ['page' => $request->page]);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean by adding it to the link to the edit page as a GET parameter?

Comment: Yes, i've updated my answer with some basic code just to show how you could implement this.